# add two pandas dataframe columns which differs by only suffix parameter for e.g., "A_x", "A_y" and rename these two columns addition with "A"

Tags: python, pandas

How to add two pandas dataframe columns which differs by only suffix parameter for e.g., "A_x", "A_y" and rename these two columns addition with "A".

For e.g., I have a data like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWs37.png)

The columns must be renamed without any of the suffix ie., to CT_1 or CT_2 etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(6)], columns=['a','s','CT_1_x','CT_1_y','CT_2_x','CT_2_y'])
print (df)
   a  s  CT_1_x  CT_1_y  CT_2_x  CT_2_y
0  0  1       2       3       4       5

df = df.set_index(['a','s']).groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], axis=1).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   a  s  CT_1  CT_2
0  0  1     5     9
```

Comment: Thanks. Now How to add both column names with same CT_1 and store the sum value into CT_1 - so in the above case the value of CT_1 should be 5?

Comment: @shravan - I think it is not necessary, completely change answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add the two columns

```
df['A'] = df['A_x'] + df['A_y']
```

and if you want to remove the original columns

```
df.drop(columns = ['A_x','A_y'])
```

If you have too many such columns `col2sum = ['A_1', 'A_2', ...]` to type by hand, the best way would be to melt the df into a long form.

```
dfm = melt(df, id_vars = ???, value_vars = col2sum)
```

and go from there (eg `groupby`) .